# Did any native US-Canadian tribes have written language before the advent of the Europeans?

Tags: native-americans

I know some peoples in more southern parts of the Americas had forms of written language, however, I was unsure as to whether this is something that had also developed among groups living in modern America-Canada prior to Columbus.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, but can't find it. Can anyone else track it down; or am I mistaken?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - I don't remember getting one quite like this before, but my memory isn't exactly renowned for its reliability.

Comment: Edited the question a tad, because I'm pretty sure the OQ wanted this restricted to the geographic areas of modern Canada and the continental United States, and thus probably isn't interested in eg: Mayan codexes.

Comment: Does the hide calendars count? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_count)

Answer (score 4):

There is/was the [Micmac writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mi%EA%9E%8Ckmaq_hieroglyphic_writing):

> Schmidt and Marshall argued in 1995 that the missionary system of the
> 17th century was able to serve as a fully functional writing system.
> This would mean that Miꞌkmaq is the oldest writing system for a native
> language north of Mexico.

(and)

> Pierre Maillard, Roman Catholic priest, during the winter of
> 1737–38 created a system of hieroglyphics to transcribe Miꞌkmaq
> words.

However, as [Barry Fell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Fell) points out, the Micmac hieroglyphics are very similar, in both form and meaning, to the Egyptian ones (*America BC*, pp. 255, 256).

[image]

And then a little mystery (p. 257):

> [Maillard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Maillard) died in 1762, 61 years before [Champollion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Fran%C3%A7ois_Champollion) published his
> first decipherment of the Egyptian hieroglyphics.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because its possible this is pre-contact, and I was previously unaware of it. However, it would be nice if this answer went into some detail about why this may qualify as an answer to the question, and also why it may not. There appear to be arguments either way.

Comment: I cannot imagine how the hieroglyph for "ram, sheep" could have been in use in Canada before European contact, given that the animal itself wasn't present on the American continent.

Comment: @Evargalo I'm not very familiar with hieroglyphics, but that is clearly not the way it works with normal words. e.g. the Ram is a Zodiac sign.

Comment: @TomasBy I am note sure I understand your comment. I just wanted to point out that *if* Mikmaks already used glyphs in the 15th century then the "Ram sheep" was certainly not one of them. Anyway, Barry Fell's work is received with a lot of skepticism by scholars - It would be nice to check if other sources found the alleged similarity between Mikmak and Egyptian hieroglyphs.

Comment: @Evargalo I believe you are wrong. They could have used that glyph as a name, or metaphorically. I agree it would be good to check Fell's tables. He does actually cite somebody else IIRC.

Comment: Is not is clear from the answer that this system was invented by the Europeans, many years after the contact? So how it addresses the question? As a proof that there was no writing before the contact?

Comment: Well, it seems doubtful to me that Maillard invented those hieroglyphics, he probably just wrote them down, but in either case the wiki quote at the top clearly suggests there were no other "US/Canadian" pre-contact writing systems.

Comment: `Wrote down' as in compiled a dictionary or whatever it was.

Comment: @Evargalo Rightly so. Anyone who has had a cursory introduction to Egyptian would have laughed this off. For all his credentials in marine biology, he's hilariously inept as a linguist and an historian, and anyone who takes this at face value might as well believe that aliens built the pyramids.

Comment: @cmw point out the problems. Point out one problem.

Comment: Evargalo already did. I'll do another one. The "glyph" for "I my me" is A1 in Gardiner and looks nothing like this. Same with the [2nd person singular pronoun](https://ancientegyptonline.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/suffix-pronouns.jpg). So many of these don't even resemble hieroglyphs at all. It's all 100% bullshit. If you've never taken Egyptian, then you don't know what you're talking about, and you shouldn't peddle the ramblings of someone the academy has regularly and routinely labeled a crackpot for [decades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Fell#Archaeology_survey).

Comment: Moreover, when would they be coming? Why would they choose the monumental script, and not hieratic or demotic? None of this makes remote sense.

Comment: I don't find Evergalos objection convincing, as I say above. You could be right, I don't know. Maybe there are several ways to express the same meaning. As to your questions in the 2nd comment, clearly what the Micmacs had, after some millenia, was a random, distorted, partial system.

Comment: And interesting quote [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Fell): (I mean I am not obsessed with this or anything) "We need to ask not only what Fell has done wrong in his epigraphy, but also where we have gone wrong as archaeologists in not recognizing such an extensive European presence in the New World."